# Three different notions for "bigness" of a module (length, rank and "mass").

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, projective-module, noetherian

Let $M$ be an $R-$module where $R$ is an integral domain. I'm trying to understand the relations between these three notions of size:

1. Let $S \subset M$ be a **generating set of minimal cardinality**. Define $|S| = mass(M)$
   (I don't know any formal term for this so i'll use this one. Sorry.).
2. Let $T \subset M$ be a **maximal linearly independent set** (A set $T$ is linearly independent iff the natural homomorphism from $R^{\oplus T}$ to $M$ is injective). Define $|T| = {rk}_R(M)$.
3. By Jordan–Hölder for modules, all **composition series** of a module have the same length. Define $length(M)$ as that length.

---

- For **vector spaces** (i .e. if $R$ is a field) all the notions coincide. (please correct me if i'm wrong).
- Suppose $M$ is **free** and of finite length. We know $M$ is free iff it admits a basis. So $M \cong R^{\oplus B}$ where $B \subset M$ is a linearly independent subset. By splitting the composition series we find that $M$ is isomorphic to a sum of simple modules. That is: $$M \cong \bigoplus_{j \in J} N_j \cong R^{\oplus B}$$
  Can we now deduce that $length(M)=mass(M)={rk}_R(M)$?
- Suppose $M$ is **projective** and of finite length. 
  We have again, by splitting, that $M \cong \bigoplus_{j \in J} N_j $. Do we have $length(M)=mass(M)$? What about ${rk}_R(M)$?
- Suppose $M$ is **noetherian**. Clearly $mass(M)$ is finite. Must $length(M)$ be finite? What if we add that $M$ is projective (/free)?

I'd like to have a more **organized picture of how these notions interact with each other** on different modules. Comprehensive answers would be greatly appreciated (and rewarded ;)).

Comment: For your second point: take $R=M=\mathbb{Z}$.  Then $M$ is of infinite length, even though it has rank and mass $1$.

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon Ah good! are the $N_j$'s always isomorphic to fields?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the $N_j$'s are... the sentence "$M$ is isomorphic to a sum of simple modules" is not true in general.  Again, take $R=M=\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship between the three numbers can be summed up in two inequalities:
$$ rk_R(M)\leq mass(M) \leq length(M) . $$
There isn't much more that can be said, see below for an idea why.

First, let us prove the inequalities.  Assume that $mass(M)=m<\infty$, and let $\{x_1, \ldots, x_m\}$ be a minimal generating set for $M$.  Then we have a strictly increasing sequence of submodules
$$Rx_1 \subset Rx_1 + Rx_2 \subset \ldots \subset Rx_1+\ldots +Rx_n=R. $$
This sequence can be refined into a composition series; hence $length(M)\geq mass(M)$.  (Note that if $mass(M)=\infty$, then the same argument shows that if $M$ has a composition series, then it is of infinite length, so we still have equality).

Next, assume that $rk_R(M)=r$, and that $mass(M)=m$.  Then there is an injective morphism $R^{\oplus r}\to M$ and a surjective morphism $R^{\oplus m}\to M$.  Since $R$ is projective, we  deduce the existence of an injective morphism $R^{\oplus r}\to R^{\oplus m}$; this implies that $r\leq m$ (since commutative rings have the [invariant basis number property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_basis_number)).  This finishes the proof of the inequalities.

---

Some comments:

- The difference between mass and rank can be arbitrarily big: over $\mathbb{Z}$, $M=\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus a}\oplus (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\oplus b}$ has rank $a$ and mass $a+b$.
- The same holds for the difference between mass and length: if $p$ is prime, then $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ has mass $1$ and length $n$ over $\mathbb{Z}$.

---

Finally, regarding, the special cases mentioned in the original question:

- As remarked in the original question, if $R$ is a field, then all three notions coincide.
- If $M$ is a free $R$-module, then $rk_R(M)=mass(M)$, and $length(M)=rk_R(M)\cdot length(R)$.
- If $M$ is projective, I don't see more what can be said.
- If $M$ is Noetherian, then $length(M)$ is only finite if $M$ is Artinian as well.

Comment: Exactly what i needed. Thanks!